# Dynamic linking paths changes for one particular project

Tags: cmake, linker

I want to use Visual Studio and gdb for editing and debugging a big open C++ project. I don't feel that 'installing' it on my computer is natural in the process of editing - compiling - debugging.

I changed the installPrefixto to something I own.

Now I can compile and install everything on this folder. But the executable look at libraries from this project in `/usr/local/lib. Is there on option I could pass to CMake to make the liking happen for libraries in my folder ?